# Regular polygons and Pythagoras

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $L_n:$ the side length of a regular $n$-polygon inscribed in a  <strike>unit</strike>
fixed circle.

We have an interesting relationship:

$L_6^2+L_6^2=L_4^2$

$L_6^2+L_4^2=L_3^2$

$L_{10}^2+L_6^2=L_5^2$

[image]

There are more solutions: $L_m^2+L_n^2=L_p^2$ ?

Comment: I think the complete set of solutions is `(3,6,2), (4,4,2), (4,6,3), (6,6,4), (6,10,5)` but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What if you want $\sum\limits_{m\in A}L_m^2 = L_n^2$, where $|A|$ need not be $2$?  Or $\sum\limits_{m\in A}L_m^2 = \sum\limits_{m\in B}L_m^2$?

Comment: I think we can consider it a problem about for each $n$ solving for $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ (each $r|n$) the equation $\sin(\frac{\pi}{n} r_1)^2 + \sin(\frac{\pi}{n} r_2)^2 = \sin(\frac{\pi}{n} r_3)^2$. The idea is that the terms are all algebraic numbers in the same field ($\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$). The key would be proving $n=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ is the biggest $n$ this can ever happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will not answer the question as phrase, but:

- The last one you list is [Proposition 10 of Book XIII of Euclid's *Elements*](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookXIII/propXIII10.html).  It [was used by Ptolemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords#How_Ptolemy_computed_chords) in the second century for constructing a trigonometric table.
- The circle need not be of unit radius.  You could have just said "inscribed in a circle".